# Plotly Dash export figure to csv

Tags: python, csv, plot, callback, plotly-dash

Unable to find anything in the official docs: How can I add a callback to my Dash app to export the data behind a `dcc.Graph` component to csv/Excel?

I understand that a `dash_table.DataTable` has an "export_format" argument to allow csv/xlsx download but how can I replicate this for graphs without the need of creating an intermediate DataTable first?

Comment: You want to convert the _data_ behind the graph (ie. list, dict, numpy array, etc.) not the graph itself or a plotly/dash component. So the question is _how to convert a list [, dict, numpy array or something] into csv ?_ The context of a Dash callback shouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: An intermediate data table? Isn't the data underlying your graph already a data table? Pandas has a `to_csv` method that should make this easy.